# How to create Personal Access Token in databricks?

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

I am new to Databricks. I have a community edition account in databricks. However, I am not able to find the `Access token` tab when I click `User Settings`. Am I missing something over here? Please help[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personal access tokens aren't supported on community edition of Databricks.